# rails delete old record while creating new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

here is my condition: i have a model named `Game` and a model named `GameLevel`, their relationship is like code below:

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :game_level

class GameLevel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game
```

here is my situation:

when a `Game` has a `GameLevel` which name is `default`, it should not have `low`, `medium`, `high`;

when a `Game` has a `GameLevel` which names are `low`, `medium`, `high`, it should not have `default`.

so how do i delete `default` when i creating(or updating when record exists) `low, medium, high` , and how do i delete `low ,medium, high` when i creating(or updating when record exists) `default` in rails model?

Comment: if there is a solution what properly is, there are still some questions like are more "same levels" allowed and how do i handle this case if not.

Comment: @devanand my solution is that define a constant array in class `GameLevel`, if more "same levels" is required, add an element to the constant, because "default" level is against all other levels. Any better suggestions from you would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `before_save` callback mentioned [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)
And you should use `game_levels` instead of `game_level` as convention.

As an example you can write something like this;

```
class GameLevel < ApplicationRecord #or ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  before_save :remove_unnecessary

  private
    def remove_unnecessary
      if self.name == "default"
        self.game.game_levels.where(name: ["low", "medium", "high"]).destroy_all()
      end
      if ["low", "medium", "high"].any?{ |type| self.name == type }
        self.game.game_levels.where(name: "default").destroy_all()
      end
    end
end
```

for destroy you can look to [here](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all)

Comment: great answer! I used your method and problem solved perfectly! ps: `destroy` requires 1 argument `id`, so I use `destroy_all` instead.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use below code**

```
class GmaeLevel < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :game
    before_save :update_date
    private
       def update_date
           self.name == "default" ? self.game.game_levels.(name: ["low","medium","high"]).destroy_all : self.game.game_levels.where(name: "default").destroy
       end
end
```

Comment: thanks for ur solution, it works as good as the above one and looks more succinct.

Comment: All the best :)